# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render when trying to access S3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, react-hooks, aws-amplify

I'm doing a small application with react where I put pictures on a private S3 bucket and only registered users can access to it. I'm not experienced at all in web design (I'm more a data scientist), so maybe the strategy I'm following isn't the most efficient one.
However, I did the registration and login with Cognito and it works properly. On the Identity pool I put a role of read to the bucket. And now I'm trying to render a sample picture in that bucket.

This is the code I have right now:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Storage } from "aws-amplify";

export default function LoadImage(props){
  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState("");

  async function onLoad(){
    try{
      const url = await Storage.get(props);
      setImgUrl(url);
    }
    catch(e){
      alert(e);
    }
  }

  onLoad();
  return(
    <img src={imgUrl} />
  );
}
```

and the intention it to use it in the `App.js` as

```
<div>{isAuthenticated ? LoadImage("img/images.png") : <>"No pic 4 u"</>}</div>
```

This code gives me the error `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.`. Bear with me, I have no idea what a hook is, as I'm picking examples of code from internet. I tried to put it directly in the `<img>` tag as

```
<div>{isAuthenticated ? <img src={Storage.get("img/images.png")} /> : <>"No pic 4 u"</>}</div>
```

but when I inspect the html it appears as

```
<div>{isAuthenticated ? <img src=[Object Promise] /> : <>"No pic 4 u"</>}</div>
```

And again, I know little about promises (from the react documentation). If I put an `alert(Storage.get("img/images.png"))` it prints the correct url.

Comment: Hooks have to start with `use` try `useLoadImage` and use it as a hook. You can't conditionally call a hook so maybe pass isAuthenticated to the custom hook and always call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you definitely should read some docs first and get used to the basics.
Anyway, here is how you should do it:

```
export default function LoadImage({link}){
  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState("");

  async function onLoad(){
    try{
      const url = await Storage.get(link);
      setImgUrl(url);
    }
    catch(e){
      alert(e);
    }
  }
  useEffect(onLoad, []);
  return(
    <img src={imgUrl} />
  );
}
```

and call it like this:

```
<div>{isAuthenticated ? <LoadImage link="img/images.png"/> : <>"No pic 4 u"</>}</div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked. However, I had to use the last line too (using it as <LoadImage link="img/images.png"/>). If I called as <img src={LoadImage("img/images.png")} /> give the "more hooks error". Now it puts an url in the src of the img tag, just it seems not to be the correct one.

Edit: in the end, the missing in my code was the useEffect (I still don't understand the hooks thing, will read the documentation and learn javascript as next project)

Answer (score 0):

It may look something like this:

```
export default function useLoadImage(url, isAuthenticated) {
  const [imgUrl, setImgUrl] = useState(
    isAuthenticated ? '' : <>"No pic 4 u"</>
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    async function onLoad() {
      try {
        const iUrl = await Storage.get(url);
        //should check if component is still mounted before trying to set state
        //https://github.com/jmlweb/isMounted
        setImgUrl(iUrl);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
    isAuthenticated && onLoad(); //only call if is authenticated
  }, [url, isAuthenticated]); //only do again if url or is authenticated changes
  return <img src={imgUrl} />;
}
//using the custom hook
const img = useLoadImage('url', isAuthenticated);
```

You should not use this hook more than once for each component. If you do need more than one image you can wrap it in a component:

```
function AmazonImage = ({url,isAuthenticated}){
  return useLoadImage(url,isAuthenticated)
}
//using the wrapper
<AmazonImage url='url' isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
```